# Samsung 950 Pro on PCIe or SATA waiting for better motherboard

Tags: ssd, motherboard, sata, pci-express

Recently Samsung has released the **950 Pro series SSDs**.

If I understand well they are only available with **M.2/PCIe connectors** which are **supported only by new motherboards**.

Is it possible to use the **950 Pro** with an older motherboard (specifically an **MSI 770-G45**) by plugging it:

1) on a **PCIe** port?

1.1) if yes is it transparent for the **BIOS** which will boot on it as usual?

2) on a **SATA** port using an **adapter**?

Indeed I expect to change my motherboard next year for one that would allow full usage of the 950 Pro.

If this is not possible I will simply fallback on a **850 Pro** plugged with **SATA**.

EDIT: beyond the physical connectors I fear the main limitation may be the new **NVMe** protocol.

Comment: @Ramhound: Asking whether an NGFF SSD can be plugged into an ordinary PCIe slot using an adapter is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Yes;  I missed the adapter portion of the question.